# Colliders no Unity3D no C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Gostaria de detectar se meu cubo a esquerda está encostando na lateral do meu cubo a direita, mas não consigo fazer isso. Existe algum método sem ter que criar objetos nulos, raycasts ou Linecast que possa me ajudar a fazer isso? [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Podes usar [OnCollisionEnter](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/detecting-collisions-oncollisionenter), ou desenhar um `raio` ([raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)) para detectar a colisão.

Comment: Podes verificar uma colisão utilizando as posições dos dois objectos...Vi que alterou a pergunta, já agora qual é a necessidade de não fazer uso de raycast e outros métodos?

Comment: Raycasts, nulos, colisores dentro de outros colisores, linecast são sistemas que não dão uma precisão tão grande, e podem ocasionar Bugs... também tem alguns sistemas que um Raycast, nulos, colisores dentro de colisores e o Linecast não poderiam ser utilizados...

Comment: Normalmente o problema não é no método de verificação da colisão em si, mas no "tempo" de execução. Por exemplo para verificar uma colisão frame por frame podes utilizar o [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Comment: Não é nem pelo próprio RayCast ser ruim... é pela circunstância onde eu uso ele ser inoportuna... por exemplo eu quero que ele detecte se o cubo colidiu **exatamente** na lateral do outro... e o RayCast tem que ter um tamanho, por exemplo 0.1, então ele nunca vai dizer se colidiu **exatamente** na lateral... e isso pode ocasionar bugs na circusntância que vou usar... espero que tenha dado pra entender...

Comment: Bom... acabei descobrindo que existe um tipo que pode detectar colisões, o Collision. Nele existe o Collision.contacts, que pode detectar em que ponto dois objetos colidiram, por exemplo a quina de um bateu no meio do outro, o lado esquerdo bateu no lado direito do outro e etc.